# AVAssetExportSession, Variable Format Profile, CABAC and reframes

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Seems that iOS 7 has decided to alter the Format Profile from 'Baseline@L4.1' to 'High@L4.0', CABAC from 'No' to 'Yes' and Reframes from 1 to 2.

This would all be well and good except that when I attempt to create a mutable composition of x files from baseline/no and y files from high/yes, we get all sorts of nastyness in the output file (quicktime on the desktop gives it some greenscreens, grayscreens.  youtube doesn't care for it either)

My question is, how can I alter the ExportSessions format profile and cabac settings to maintain a consistency.

Note this (currently) only affects iPhone5s, 4s, 4ses, and iPads up to 3 seem to maintain the Baseline and Cabac settings as before, keeping it consistent with what iOS 6 dictacted.

Thanks

Comment: Have you figured out a solution for this? I'm dealing with the same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can replace `AVAssetExportSession` with [`SDAVAssetExportSession`](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession). You can then specify settings instead of using presets which provide different results across different devices.